# Const char... changed?

Tags: c++

This is a portion of my simple program

```
string appData = getenv("APPDATA");
const char *mypath= (appData+"\\MyApplication\\hello.txt").c_str();      
cout << mypath;  
// output: c:\users\xrobot\appdata\Roaming\Myapplication\hello.txt   
fstream file(mypath,ios::in);
ofstream filetemp;    
filetemp.open("world.bak");
cout << mypath;  
// output: É↕7
```

Why is mypath changed in that weird string ?

Comment: I am surprised that this code compiles. you are treating a cstring like a std::string.

Comment: If you get the output "c:\users\xrobot\appdata\Roaming\Myapplication\hello.txt" in line 4, I don't believe the snippet here is the actual code you are running. Rather, I would expect a compiler error on the second line. Can we see the actual code? From the symptoms you give, I suspect in your real code you are calling c_str() on a std::string and retaining the returned pointer while leaving the scope the std::string was declared in. Don't do that, hang on to the std::string instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `std::string` as:

```
std::string appData = getenv("APPDATA");
std::string path = appData+"\\MyApplication\\hello.txt";
```

then do this:

```
const char * mypath = path.c_str();
```

Note that you **must not** do this:

```
const char* mypath = (appData+"\\MyApplication\\hello.txt").c_str();
```

It is because expression on the right hand side is a temporary which gets destroyed at the end of the expression and `mypath` will continue to point to the destroyed object. It becomes a dangling pointer, in other words.

--

> Why is mypath changed in that weird string ?

Because in your posted code, `mypath` is a dangling pointer, using which invokes undefined behavior.

**This is how you should write the code:**

```
std::string appData = getenv("APPDATA");
std::string mypath= appData+"\\MyApplication\\hello.txt";
cout << mypath;  
fstream file(mypath.c_str(),ios::in);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't add two strings like that.  You should receive a clear warning.  Since you're using C++, you may want to use `std::string` instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a temporary `std::string`:

```
(appData+"\\MyApplication\\hello.txt")
```

So the underlying C string space can be freed after the expression is used. Since you have a `char*` pointing to what's now garbage memory, you have a funky value.

Comment: Ewwwwww. What's the point of using `std::string` if you're going back to the unsafe `strxxx` interface at the first opportunity?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes The OP seems adamant about not using `strcat()`. His funeral.