# How to return a char* from a function in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I have the following function in c++

```
    char* Test::convertToSHA(const char* cc) {

    const char* salt ="sh$^$#@!&7hbfvatfacv@@@@bagg=shjgvshvcbschj";
    time_t currentTime;
    time(&currentTime);
    CCString startTimeString;
    startTimeString.createWithFormat("%d", currentTime);

    std::string s = cc;
    s += startTimeString.getCString();
    s += salt;

    char *str = new char[strlen(s.c_str()) +  1];
    int length=strlen(str);
    unsigned char hash[length*2];
    char hexstring[41];
    sha1::calc(str,length,hash);
    sha1::toHexString(hash, hexstring);

    return hexstring;
}
```

And in the call i use

```
char* output=NULL;
output= Test::convertToSHA("hello");
```

This is causing my code to crash. Is there a problem with me returning a string ? How can i return from this function ?

Comment: This should really just return a `std::string`.

Comment: Do NOT return stack variables. Either `new hexstring`, or let the caller to allocate memory and pass it to `convertToSHA`. But the better way is to return std::string (or return by reference) since you're using c++.

Comment: Can u please show me how ?

Comment: The caller does not know how much memory to allocate ?

Comment: @BadLuckBrian Won't it always be 41?

Comment: Why are you creating (and forgetting to populate) a temporary buffer, `str`? You could just write `sha1::calc(s.data(), s.length(), hash);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using this [library](http://code.google.com/p/smallsha1/source/browse/trunk/sha1.cpp). I find it odd that it claims to be written in `C++` but doesn't take advantage of `C++` idioms. The function modifies the pointer, and doesn't return anything, so you do need a local variable. Lucky for you, `std::string`s will happily accept a `char []` argument.

```
std::string Test::convertToSHA(const char* cc) {
    // ...
    char hexstring[41];
    sha1::calc(str,length,hash);
    sha1::toHexString(hash, hexstring);
    std::string ret(hexstring);

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks. I do use that Library. Its working now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

[You can never return a local pointer in C or C++.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20063660/1530508) Instead, either pass the pointer as a parameter:

```
void Test::convertToSHA(const char* cc, const char* hexstring) {

   //no change to body
   //no return statement needed
}

//then when calling the function:

char hexstring[41];

convertToSHA(cc, hexstring);

//hexstring has been modified
```

Or just use `std::string` instead. Use the `c_str()` if you need to convert to a c-style string (you still can't return the pointer, though).

Comment: I have modified the code. Its still crashing.

Comment: @BadLuckBrian Show us the new code.