# Store returned array from a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, return-value

I am just trying to make a simple two player game. First player enters the movie and second player guesses it by using some basics of C++.

```
movie[] = entered by player 1.
movie_temp[]= a temp array with '_' in it. It updates after every guess by player 2.
```

MY PROBLEM: Please refer the main function where I called the function `movie_check()`.
This updates the life after every guess. I want the same to happen for my `movie_temp array`.
When I run this program, only the lives are updated properly, on correct guess the lives are not reduced, but in next turn the `array_temp` is not updated and the same array is displayed again and again after each gas.

Please help me to create a function which helps to return array and save it in `movie_temp` (just as I did for life).

IDE: Code::Blocks
Compiler: GCC Compiler

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>

void display_movie(char movie_temp[], int);
void display_life(int);
int win_player2(char movie_temp[]);
int check_life(char movie[], char, int);


void display_movie(char movie_temp[], int len)
{
    for(int i=0 ; i<len ; i++)
        cout<<movie_temp[i];
}

void display_life(int life)
{
    for(int i=0 ; i<=life ; i++)
        cout<<"\3";
}


int check_life(char movie[], char ch, int life)
{
    int count1=0;
    for(int i=0 ; movie[i]!='\0' ; i++)
    {
        if(movie[i]==ch)
            count1++;
    }
    if(count1==0)
        return --life;
    else
        return life;
}

int win_player2(char movie_temp[])
{
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0 ; movie_temp[i]!='\0' ; i++)
   {
       if(movie_temp[i]=='_')
           count++;
   }
   if(count==0)
        return 0;
   else
        return 1;
}


int main()
{
    char movie[100], movie_temp[100], ch;
    cout<<"Enter the movie: ";
    cin.getline(movie,100);
    int len= strlen(movie);
    system("cls");


    for(int i=0 ; movie[i]!='\0' ; i++)
    {
        if(movie[i]=='a' || movie[i]=='e' || movie[i]=='i' || movie[i]=='o' ||
        movie[i]=='u' || movie[i]==' ')
            movie_temp[i]= movie[i];
        else
            movie_temp[i]='_';
    }

    int life=9;
    cout<<"\nLives left: ";
    display_life(life);


    while(life!=0 || win_player2(movie_temp)!=0)
    {
        cout<<"\n";
        display_movie(movie_temp, len);
        cout<<"\nEnter your guess: ";
        cin>>ch;
        life=check_life(movie, ch, life);
        cout<<"\n\nLives left: ";
        display_life(life);

    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}

enter code here
```

Comment: This would be SO much easier with `std::string`.

Comment: And if you're using conio.h, why not just use `clrscr()` instead of `system("cls")`?

Comment: Seems more like C tending to be C++. Other than `cout` and `cin` everything seems to be C. Use C++ structures to make your life a lot easier.

Comment: The `count1=0;` right after `return life;` is unreachable code (it's also redundant, since it's only executed if `count1 == 0` in the first place). Do turn up your warning level to catch stuff like this.

Comment: @FredLarson : I am a C++ beginner. I don't have any idea about std::string. Just help me make out this program. The logic's is almost correct. Just need some professional's touch.

Comment: @lazygeek: All the more reason to use C++ features that make your life easier. Arrays are very easily misused in C++ and are best left to the experts (who avoid them when they can).

Comment: @lazygeek If whatever you're learning from hasn't mentioned std::string, I'd recommend you [pick up a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242) and learn how to use the features of the the language you're using.

Comment: [You can't return arrays from functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20063617/1530508).

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart : Yes I googled it a lot. Everyone's saying something about pinters. But I dont get it.
Can you please give me a simple (very simple) example explaining returning array through pointers.
I want to save that returned value into some main function. Please help me :)

Comment: @lazygeek Arrays are pointers, so your premise of "write a function that returns an array" is flawed.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart : I know its flawed. Thats why I am here. Stop pointing my faults and give me a simple example.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart : I just realized some of the blunders I made. Here's the code with some major corrections:

http://pastebin.com/0T2U1aan

Comment: @lazygeek - I updated my answer with some more information on "how to return arrays from functions". Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

You make the usual mistake:

```
            movie_temp[i]==movie[i];
```

should be

```
            movie_temp[i]=movie[i];
```

Your compiler should have been screaming a warning at you... mine did:

```
note: use '=' to turn this equality comparison into an assignment
                movie_temp[i]==movie[i];
```

Context (in case you have trouble finding the line):

```
    if(movie[i]==ch)
        {
            movie_temp[i]==movie[i];   // <<<<<<<<<< this is the line that doesn't copy!
            count1++;
        }
```

**update** just following the warnings that the compiler was giving me, I made a few small changes to your code and now it is working. Mostly, I was heeding the "you are not returning a value!" types of warnings (when you don't explicitly return a value, the compiler will make something up - and most likely you won't find the result useful).

The key is to move the line

```
return movie_temp;
```

outside of the `for` loop in `check_movie2`:

```
char* check_movie2(char movie[], char movie_temp[], char ch)
{
    for(int i=0 ; movie[i]!='\0' ; i++)
    {
        if(movie[i]==ch)
            {
                movie_temp[i]=movie[i];
            }
    }
    return movie_temp;
}
```

There are other problems - but this is the one that was biting you the hardest.

Lesson learnt: if your compiler is warning you, LISTEN.

For your entertainment here is the code that I got to run (and that "mostly works". It doesn't currently print out lives correctly and it asks for input after I guessed the title. Also you might consider making the comparison case-insensitive as you are currently sensitive to correct capitalization).

**updated** added some comments and additional fixes in your code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;  // <<<< if you want to use 'cout' instead of 'std::cout' etc, you need this

void display_movie(char movie_temp[], int);
void display_life(int);
int win_player2(char movie_temp[]); 
int check_movie(char movie[], char movie_temp[], char, int);
void display_movie(char movie_temp[], int len)
{
    for(int i=0 ; i<len ; i++)
    cout<<movie_temp[i];
}

void display_life(int life) //displays lives left after each guess
{
    for(int i=0 ; i<=life ; i++)
    cout<<"+";     // <<<<< I don't know what you are hoping to print with "\3"
                   // <<<<< Remember that `\` has a special meaning inside a string!
}


int check_movie(char movie[], char movie_temp[], char ch, int life)
{
    int count1=0;
    for(int i=0 ; movie[i]!='\0' ; i++)
    {
        if(tolower(movie[i])==tolower(ch))    // <<<<< consider case insensitive match 
            {
                movie_temp[i]=movie[i];
                count1++;
            }
    }
    if(count1==0)
        {
            life--;
            return life;    //if none of the character is found, life is reduced by 1.
            count1=0;
        }
    return life; // <<<<<< return life here    
}

int win_player2(char movie_temp[])
{
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0 ; movie_temp[i]!='\0' ; i++)
    {
        if(movie_temp[i]=='_')
            count++;
    }  
    return (count==0)?0:1;
}

char* check_movie2(char movie[], char movie_temp[], char ch)
{
    for(int i=0 ; movie[i]!='\0' ; i++)
    {
        if(movie[i]==ch)
            {
                movie_temp[i]=movie[i];
            }
    }
    return movie_temp;
}

int main()
{
    char movie[100], movie_temp[100], ch;
    cout<<"Enter the movie: ";
    cin.getline(movie,100);
    int len= strlen(movie);
    int life=9;
    system("cls");


    for(int i=0 ; movie[i]!='\0' ; i++)
    {
        if(movie[i]=='a' || movie[i]=='e' || movie[i]=='i' || movie[i]=='o' ||
        movie[i]=='u' || movie[i]==' ')
        movie_temp[i]= movie[i];
    else
        movie_temp[i]='_';
    }    //initially displays the movie to player 2 and shows only vowels.

    cout<<"\nLives left: ";
    display_life(life);


    while(life!=0 && win_player2(movie_temp)!=0)  // <<<<< change || to &&
    {
        cout<<"\n";
        display_movie(movie_temp, len);
        cout<<"\nEnter your guess: ";
        cin>>ch;
        life=check_movie(movie, movie_temp, ch, life); 

        /*I need to update the life after each round, or else the initially declared              
         life is passed. */

        cout<<"\n\nLives left: ";
        display_life(life);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE** - "returning pointers from functions"

To "return an array of values", you need to realize a number of things:

1. A function can only "return" a simple value (int, float, pointer, ...)
2. If you create an array inside a function, you need to make sure the
   space allocated remains valid after you return
3. You can pass a pointer to a function, and let the function update values in the space pointer to

Simple example (C) on different approaches (including one that doesn't work):

**does not work:**

```
   int * foo() {
     int A[]={1,2,3,4,5};
     return A;
   }

int main(void) {
  int *X;
  X = foo();
  printf("%d", X[0]);  // UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR
  return 0;
}
```

This doesn't work because the array `A` stops existing ('goes out of scope') when the function returns. Accessing memory pointed to by `X` results in undefined behavior.

**works, but only use in single threaded environment:**

```
   int * foo() {
     static int A[]={1,2,3,4,5};
     return A;
   }
```

this works because the array is `static` so it is allocated differently and "survives" after the function returns. Not recommended.

**pass a pointer and size of array:** (example increments an array)

```
void foo(int *a, int n) {
  int ii;
  for(ii=0;ii<n;ii++) a[ii]++;
}

int main(void) {
  int n=5;
  int X[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  foo(X, 5);  // values in X will be incremented in-place
```

Returning value in another array:

```
void foo(int *A, int *B, int n) {
  int ii;
  for(ii=0; ii<n; ii++) B[ii] = 2 * A[ii];
}

int main(void) {
  int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  int b[5];
  foo(a, b, 5);
  printf("%d\n", b[0]);  // returns a value of 2
  return 0;
}
```

This is starting to be more sensible. Finally, if you want an array to be created by the function, you can do

```
int *foo(int n) {
  int *X, ii;
  X = malloc(n * sizeof *X);
  for(ii = 0; ii < n; ii++) X[ii] = 2 * ii;
  return X;
}

int main(void) {
  int *a;
  a = foo(5);
  printf("%d", a[4]); // will print 8
  free(a);  // remember to do this after you finished using the array or you get a memory leak!
  return 0;
}
```

I hope these additional examples and their explanation improves your understanding of these techniques a little bit.

Comment: Oh yeah. I figured that out. Silly me. But when i apply that assignment symbol, there's infinite loop printing endless hearts ("\3")

Comment: Please help me with returning an array with the function.

Comment: Thanks @floris for your suggestions.
I am looking forward to consider case insensitivity.

Comment: I made some few changes. Please check out the code again.

Comment: I don't know why you made those changes - you are now much further from your goal than before. Did you try running the code I posted above?